# How to call HTML popup page from AngularJS side?

Tags: html, angularjs, popupwindow

The question is: **How to call popup page from AngularJS side?**

Currently I have **popup** page shown on anchor HREF click in HTML like this:

[image: Popup page called from HTML Anchor element click]

1) the HTML part is following:

```
<modal lolo="modal1" modal-body="body" modal-footer="footer" modal-header="header" template-url="contactus"></modal>

<a href="#{{modal1}}" target="_self" role="button" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a>
```

2) the directives created in AngularJS side:

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module("app")

    .directive('modal', function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'EA',
            scope : {
                title : '=modalTitle',
                header : '=modalHeader',
                body : '=modalBody',
                footer : '=modalFooter',
                callbackbuttonleft : '&ngClickLeftButton',
                callbackbuttonright : '&ngClickRightButton',
                handler : '=lolo'
            },
            templateUrl : function(elem, attrs) {
                if (attrs) {

                    if (attrs.templateUrl === 'sendverify') {
                        return "./pages/register/sendverificationcode.html";
                    } else if (attrs.templateUrl === 'contactus') {
                        return "./pages/contact/contact_us.html";
                    }
                }
            },
            transclude : true,
            controller : function($scope, $attrs) {
                $scope.handler = $attrs.templateUrl;
            },

        };
    })
}(angular));
```

3) And contact_us.html :

```
<div id="{{handler}}" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          <h2>{{header}}</h2>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
          <p>
            <b>HAVE A QUESTION OR COMMENT? NEED HELP?</b>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>How can we be of service? For answers to all your questions, call us. We 're happy to help. Or, send us an email below and we 'll get back to you as soon as we can.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button>1-844-WHATEVER(123-4567)</button>
        <button>hello@whatever.com</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine, you click CONTACT Anchor element and it shows the popup, but **How to call popup page from AngularJS side?**. For example you have some logic in AngularJS and based on the result you call the pop up and pass some other data to it to display?

Comment: Here's a good resource for Angular modals using ui-bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal